# Gnu screen: kill a frozen tab

Tags: tabs, gnu-screen

How to go about closing a stalled screen tab (the machine is no longer reachable) ?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

try to `kill` command.

1. select stalled window ( `C-a` `:select <stalled window number>` )
2. send kill command ( `C-a` `:kill` )

Comment: at least for my screen version, I get a message that :kill is ambiguous.  :kill-window works, though.

Comment: `C-a, k` also works

Answer (score 8):

The most simple and direct way, which has always worked for me, is

```
C-a, k
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using the OpenSSH client to connect, you can type `Enter` `~` `.` to close the connection.

To list the other SSH client escape commands, type `Enter` `~` `?` when connected.

Comment: Why the down vote? This addresses the "machine is no longer reachable" aspect of the question directly. Sure you can do other things to close a remote connection (eg: shut down your computer), but that doesn't directly address the stalled remote connection.

Comment: Thanks I had a runaway shell command, screen would not respond to any Ctrl + A command, but this worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an unresponsive tab, oftentimes you cannot navigate into the tab itself; to kill a stalled tab/window from another tab:

`C-a: at "<tabNum>#" kill`, i.e. to kill tab 7, `C-a: at "7#" kill`

To kill an individual tab in a detached GNU Screen session:

`screen -XS <sessID> -p <tabNum> kill`

Hope someone finds this useful...